# media querys для js

Tags: javascript, события, media-queries

Добрый день друзья, есть js скрипт выполняющий определенные действия на веб-странице, мне нужно чтобы он выполнялся только при определенных разрешениях экрана. Как я понимаю для его нужно поместить в определенный обработчик (своего рода `media query`) для js. Подскажите или какой обработчик мне нужно использовать или небольшой пример, как на css примерно

```
 ( @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример по ширине при помощи Jquery

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {     
  //код 
}
```

Вот пример по ширине при помощи Javascript:

```
if (window.screen.availWidth < 768) {     
  //код 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нативными средствами вот так:

```
ширина = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
высота = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Потом через условие, например так:

```
if (ширина > 1000) {
  element.display = 'block';
}
```

Подробнее вот тут: [Как найти ширину окна браузера?](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window)